# SwiperJs - How to show 1 half slides and 1 full slides

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I have two images.
I want to use swiperjs 11.0.4 in ReactJs and show 1 full slide in the center and then a half slide either side and can loop. I assume this is possible but can't work out how.

Can anyone advise? Want to recreate the below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ALiI.png)

I try slidesPerView={1.5} and centeredSlides but not ok. It's like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vOFG.png)

Comment: What if you try to add prop loop={true} ? So the first half blank should be Slide 2 either

Comment: @Guillaume i added loop={true] and it still blank like image example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.